# imagemagick: crop one image to four not equal size parts, but but keep original canvas size and paint background transparent

Tags: bash, image, shell, imagemagick, crop

I have a 1920X1920 ratio image like below:
[image: origial image]

I want to crop this original image so that it is divided into four parts.
[image]
In the end it has the effect of forming four pictures, each of which is the original size.
[image]

I have used such a command, but this intelligence forms two pictures up and down, and cannot form four transparent pictures

```
convert lena.png -crop 1x2@ +adjoin lena_%02d.miff
for img in *.miff; do
name=$(convert $img -format %t info:)
convert $img -background transparent -flatten $name.png
done
rm -f *.miff
```

Excuse me, is there a very elegant way to achieve the effect I dream of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: Since the image you're probably working with is not the image you posted, you will need to modify this code to suit your purposes.

```
#!/bin/bash

width=$(convert lena.png -format "%w" info:)
height=$(convert lena.png -format "%h" info:)

# Get the Percentage of the Width
pct_w() {
  echo $(($1*$width/100))
}

# Get the Percentage of the Height
pct_h() {
  echo $(($1*$height/100))
}

# Top-Left
convert lena.png -crop $(pct_w 33)x$(pct_h 50)+0+0 +adjoin top-left.miff
convert top-left.miff -background transparent -flatten top-left.png

# Top-Right
convert lena.png -crop $(pct_w 66)x$(pct_h 50)+$(pct_w 33)+0 +adjoin top-right.miff
convert top-right.miff -background transparent -flatten top-right.png

# Bottom-Left
convert lena.png -crop $(pct_w 65)x$(pct_h 50)+0+$(pct_h 50) +adjoin bottom-left.miff
convert bottom-left.miff -background transparent -flatten bottom-left.png

# Bottom-Right
convert lena.png -crop $(pct_w 35)x$(pct_h 50)+$(pct_w 65)+$(pct_h 50) +adjoin bottom-right.miff
convert bottom-right.miff -background transparent -flatten bottom-right.png

rm *.miff
```

There are two helper functions to calculate percentages for Width and Height. In the code `$(pct_w 33)` this refers to 33% of the width. Change these values accordingly until you get the cuts you want.

Comment: `convert lena.png -crop 530x540+0+0 +adjoin -background transparent -flatten  top-left.png`

Comment: ratio is 1920*1080

Comment: Ok cool, you got it, If I knew the original dimensions that would've been easier from the start. I thought you might like the percentage functions so it could scale if the dimensions ever changed.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to answer you properly without actual images and dimensions, but let's try to get you there.

We'll make 4 images and send them to `montage` to make a 4-image montage, laid out as 2 rows and 2 columns:

```
magick -size 240x120              \
    xc:red  -write miff:- +delete \
    xc:lime -write miff:- +delete \
    xc:blue -write miff:- +delete \
    xc:black miff:- | magick montage -background yellow -geometry +10+10 miff:- result.png
```

Hopefully all the different colours and backgrounds will let you see what that is doing.

---

Now, instead of sending 4 solid blocks of colour, we'll

- crop out the pieces you want - my numbers will be wrong, but you should see how they work,
- set the gravity so that they extend in the correct direction,
- extend them, and
- send them to a final `montage` command for assembly - exactly as shown above.

---

```
magick YOURIMAGE \
   \( +clone -crop 200x100+10+10   -gravity northwest -background red -extent 300x200 -write miff:- +delete \) \
   \( +clone -crop 200x100+200+10  -gravity northeast -background lime -extent 300x200 -write miff:- +delete \) \
   \( +clone -crop 200x100+10+100  -gravity southwest -background blue -extent 300x200 -write miff:- +delete \) \
             -crop 200x100+200+100 -gravity southeast -background black -extent 300x200 -write miff:- | magick montage ...
```

---

Practice cropping out just one section of your image on its own, setting gravity and background and then extending and saving:

```
magick YOURIMAGE -crop 200x100+20+40 -gravity southeast -background cyan -extend 800x400 result.png
```

Comment: I want four images result not finally all in one.